# How can I Execute/Call a user-space defined function from Linux kernel space module?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am developing a Linux module which I want to use to **run my C program from kernel mode**.

My problem here, in function `read()` of the module, I need to use a function named `eval_keycode()`, which is defined in my user space program.

When I try to compile my module, this error occurs :

> error: implicit declaration of function ‘eval_keycode’

which is confirming my problem described above.

This is the `read()` function of my module :

```
ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {
    struct file *f = pfile->private_data;
    enum { MAX_BUF_SIZE = 4096 };
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t rc = 0;

    struct input_event  *ev;
    int yalv;

    /* Allocate temporary buffer. */
    if (length) {
        buf_size = min_t(size_t, MAX_BUF_SIZE, length);
        ev = kmalloc(buf_size, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (ev == NULL) {
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    }

    /* Read file to buffer in chunks. */
    do {
        size_t amount = min_t(size_t, length, buf_size);

        rc = kernel_read(f, ev, amount, offset);
        if (rc > 0) {
            /* Have read some data from file. */
            if (copy_to_user(buffer, ev, rc) != 0) {
                /* Bad user memory! */
                rc = -EFAULT;
            } else {
                /* Update totals. */
                total += rc;
                buffer += rc;
                *offset += rc;
                length -= rc;

        for (yalv = 0; yalv < (int) (rc / sizeof(struct input_event)); yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                    eval_keycode(ev[yalv].code);
            }
        }


                if (rc < amount) {
                    /* Didn't read the full amount, so terminate early. */
                    rc = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    while (rc > 0 && length > 0);

    /* Free temporary buffer. */
    kfree(buf);

    if (total > 0) {
       return total;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

This is my user space `eval_keycode()` defined function :

```
void eval_keycode(int code)
{
    static int red_state = 0;
    static int green_state = 0;

    switch (code) {
    case 260:
        printf("BTN left pressed\n");

        /* figure out red state */
        red_state = red_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" red "/brightness", red_state);
        break;

    case BTN_RIGHT:
        printf("BTN right pressed\n");

        /* figure out green state */
        green_state = green_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", green_state);
        break;
    }
}
```

How can call the `eval_keycode` function from user space in order to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: The message tells you that you must declare the eval_keycode PROTOTYPE first. Consider adding 'void eval_keycode(int code);' before the `read` function to pass compilation, and will allow you to move forward to the next problem

Comment: @dash-o I added eval_keycode(int code); before read function, now, the compilation goes right, but I cant insert the module to the kernel and showing me : `Unknown symbol eval_keycode (err 0) , unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter`

Comment: I don't really know why you are going about things this way. Can't you do it all in userspace?

Comment: Just copy the `eval_keycode` code into the kernel or do it all in userspace. There is no way to "call a function from userspace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it is a really bad idea. You need to establish a pointer to your user mode function, arrange for the process containing that function to be running (in the kernel) when you invoke it.  That is a lot of work, and is fundamentally malware due to the security holes it creates. Additionally, in the mad dash to lock the door to the now empty barn in the wake of spectre et al,  new layers of  hackery are being deployed in newer CPUs to make this even harder.

A different approach:

In your original query, you are running this driver as a "tee"; that is, you take the input you receive from the device, give a copy to the caller, and call eval_keycode with each input.  Eval_keycode doesn't modify the data, and the kernel module discards it afterwards.   So Eval_keycode doesn't really need to be a function; or rather, there could be a user function:

```
void ProcessEvents(int fd) {
    struct input_event ev;
    while (read(fd, &ev, sizeof ev) == sizeof ev) {
        eval_keycode(&ev);
    }
}
```

if you could arrange for all the events to be fed into that fd.   With this setup, your problem becomes more plumbing than kernel renovation.  The user creates a pipe/socket/fifo/... and passes the write end to your kernel module (yay more ioctl()s).  Your kernel module can then carefully use kernel_write() ( or vfs_write if you are stuck in the past ) to make these events available to the user handler.  It wants to be careful about where its blocking points are.

You could extend this to work as a transform; that is where your driver transforms the events via a user mode handler; but at that point, you might really consider FUSE a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no traditional (in the way a library works) way to "call" a user space "function".

Your user space code should be running in its' own process (or another user space process), in which you would implement communications (through shared memory, interprocess calls [IPC], device files, interrupts..) where you handle the exchange of data, and act on the data (e.g. calling your eval_keycode function).

Answer (score 0):

You basically want an upcall. You can find some explanation about that [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/724173/), but [it doesn't seem](http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/Upcall-implementation-in-Linux-td150112.html) like Linux has an official upcall API.

However, as others have already mentioned, this isn't very good design. Upcalls are useful to servers implemented in the kernel.

If your `exer_read()` is only called for your own code (on your files for which you're implementing the driver), then perhaps [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) would be a better design.

If your `exer_read()` can be called for any file (e.g. you want any file write on the machine to change the LED state), then you want your userspace process containing `eval_keycode()` to poll some character device, and you want your module to write the code to this character device instead of calling `eval_keycode()`.

If, however, `change_led_state()` is synchronous, and you actually need the read to block until it returns, then you are advised to reconsider your design... but that's a valid use case for upcalls.